# Approximate dollar MTM of interest rate swaps

Tags: interest-rates, swaps, interest-rate-swap

I'm definitely a fixed income tourist but I'm wondering if there's an easy way to back of the envelope approximate dollar PnL of an interest rate swap

For example, if I enter a $1m fixed 5y USD swap at 3% and tomorrow the quote rises 5bps to 3.05%, assuming I know the carry X bps and rolldown Y bps, what is my dollar PnL of the position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only one day has elapsed, the carry and roll down effect on the p/l is insignificant.  The p/l is well approximated simply by multiplying the move in the quotation by the duration of the swap, which in the case of a 5yr swap is around 4.5.  So the p/l would be 4.5*0.05%*1MM = about 2250 dollars.

Comment: Gotcha thanks! Why is the duration on a 5y around 4.5 years? Is it because the payments are semi annual? So for 10y would the duration be 9.5 years?

Comment: It’s just the value of a 1bp annuity, calculated at prevailing interest rate.  It would be more like 9.0 for a 10yr.

Comment: ah thanks! do you by chance have any reference/ info on how to do the calculation?